What is the minimum torque for a wheel to overcome an obstacle?
If I have a standard wheel with a motor attached, trying to overcome a vertical obstacle with height less than or equal to its radius, what is the minimum torque required from the motor to do so? Assume that the wheel pivots around the blue point (no slipping). I guess this question also translates to: how does torque convert into force?


Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/338644/sphere-rolling-up-a-step

This is cool, thanks! This post is assuming that the sphere is already having an initial velocity. I was wondering if there is a critical value for the torque when the sphere/wheel is at rest.

Possible duplicate of Rotational mechanics - ball climbing a step
