# Doubt in cylinder going up a step at constant angular speed

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, rotational-dynamics

I have this problem here:

[image: Problem]
I think I know how to solve everything except for the number 2). I studied in the mechanics subject that $W_{ext}=K_{2}-K_{1}$. Where $W_{ext}$ is the external forces' work and $K_2$ and $K_1$ are the Kinetic energies in the moment 2 and 1, respectively.

For 3) I suppose I can use :
$W_{ext}=-mgh$
and $K_1=\frac{1}{2}mV^2+\frac{1}{2}I\dot{\theta}'^2=\frac{1}{2}m(r\dot{\theta}')^2+\frac{1}{2}(\frac{1}{2}mr^2)\dot{\theta}'^2=\frac{3}{4}mr^2\dot{\theta}'^2$
Equally, $K_2=\frac{3}{4}mr^2\dot{\theta}''^2$
Therefore $-mgh=\frac{3}{4}mr^2\dot{\theta}''^2-\frac{3}{4}mr^2\dot{\theta}'^2\rightarrow \dot{\theta}''=\sqrt{\frac{\frac{3}{4}mr^2\dot{\theta}'^2-mgh}{\frac{3}{4}mr^2}}=\sqrt{\dot{\theta}'^2-\frac{4gh}{3r^2}}$

And for 4), I can just equal the kinetic energy to the potential energy necessary for climbing the step, so
$\frac{3}{4}mr^2\dot{\theta}_{min}'^2=mgh\rightarrow \dot{\theta}_{min}'=\sqrt{\frac{4gh}{3r^2}}$. Which makes sense comparing it to the solution in 3).

Are the approaches I used in this two parts correct? Because when I try to use this in 2), as just after it collided there is not a change in the height and therefore the $W_{ext}=0$, and that just at the colission the velocity is $0$, $\dot{\theta}'=3\dot{\theta}$, which doesn't make sense for me. Could you help me with this?

Thank you very much

Comment: Angular momentum about $P$ is conserved during the "collision" with the step edge.

Comment: But at the moment of collision the angular velocity should decrease, so there should be a angular acceleration and therefore $\sum{\vec{M}}\neq 0$ right? so the angular momentum shouldn't be conserved. Or am I making a mistake here?

Answer (score 0):

Angular momentum about P is conserved during the "collision" with the step edge

The reason why conservation of angular momentum can be used is similar to the answer given to this question [Can linear momentum be conserved before and after collision in the presence of an external force?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/310540/can-linear-momentum-be-conserved-before-and-after-collision-in-the-presence-of-a/310609#310609).

Let the system be the cylinder.
The two external torques about $P$ which act during the "collision" between the cylinder and the step are due to the weight of the cylinder and the force $F$.
As the line of action of force $N$ passes through $P$ the torque about $P$ due to this force is zero.
Although there are there two external torques acting on the cylinder these two torques only act for a relatively short period of time during the "collision" and so the sum of the impulsive external torques (which is equal to the change in angular momentum) is very small and can be neglected in this case.

Comment: I see! it makes sense. Thank you very much for explaining it :)