# Should time period of collision be small to apply conservation of momentum?

Tags: classical-mechanics, momentum

[How does conservation of momentum change in moving frames ( constant velocity ) and non-inertial frames?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/545950/how-does-conservation-of-momentum-change-in-moving-frames-constant-velocity)

In this question's accepted answer, it says that if the time period of application of pseudo force is negligible, then the conservation of momentum holds. But I have learnt that momentum is always conserved? Where does this aspect of time period come into the picture?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason we require a small impact/collision time for momentum conservation is quite simple. If we want to believe we can neglect external forces like friction or drag for the instant that the collision happens, then **the collision time has to be very small so that these forces don't have enough time to dissipate the momentum of the colliding bodies.** We can therefore, safely assume that only the mutual internal forces between the bodies act during the short-impact time. It's important however, to understand that impact time will not matter if external forces can actually be neglected.

Answer (score 2):

Momentum conservation applies to systems that are translationally invariant, so if your system is accelerating, there is an omnipresent pseudo-force, $\vec g$, that breaks translational invariance. If the acceleration is uniform, you can consider a potential energy, $\phi$, such that:

$$ \vec g = -\vec{\nabla}\phi(\vec x) $$

The system now has a position dependent energy; it is not invariant under all translations, and momentum is not conserved. For example, if you drop a ball: it gains momentum in the direction of $\vec g$.

Regarding the linked answer; here is an example. If you are studying collisions on a frame with position dependent potential energy, say 2 billiard balls on a slightly tilted table (or perhaps golf putting on a difficult green), you are going to have to consider $\phi({\vec x})$ in estimating the run-out of your shot (aka: reading the green), but it does not factor into the collision.

If you want a certain speed and direction for your billiard ball, you can use your "level-table" shot skill set. As the other answer points out, the collision forces are much, much, greater than $m\vec{g}$, and the quicker the collision, the greater the ratio.

Comment: I dont quite get your point . Why does this additional force /potential field require a small collision time